# flutter doctor not recognized from flutter console

Tags: flutter

[image]

I was working with flutter for sometimes, but suddenly it started as the device not recognized from the android studio, then i tried flutter doctor from console and below message showing, please some one help me.

Comment: you need to export your path correctly

Answer (score 0):

try adding flutter to your path env

read [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#update-your-path) the **Update your path** part

Comment: This didn't solve my issue, I have removed the flutter and copied new one solved the issue